# How to connect Pipes in Revit with less than 10deg angle

Tags: revit

I am working on a REVIT model for site external services. In this project, Water supply & Chilled water pipes are running with different invert level due to varying ground profile to maintain proper depth pipe protection. Due to ground level, pipes are running in different slope. Angles are too small between pipes.
Now I am enable to connect two pipes with different angle.
I have changed Mechanical pipe setting – Angle.
I have changed Elbow family setting.
But pipes are not connected below 10 deg automatically with trim command.
Is there any trick to connect these pipes?
Please gives your valuable suggestion for this.
Image are attached for reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrS27.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you first of all research how to solve this manually through the user interface. Once that is sorted out, you can start exploring how to automate it via the API. Here is a suggestion from The Building Coder on [how to research to find a Revit API solution](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/virtues-of-reproduction-research-mep-settings-ontology.html#3).